# How to manipulate objects after JSON list deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to work with JSON files to store a Class and I'm stuck with the deserialization.

I'm using the following NameSpace:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

I have a very simple class, made of 2 properties:

```
public EnumOfType Type { get; set; }
public double Price { get; set; }
```

I have 4 instances of this classe that I store in a list. When quiting the application, this list is saved in a JSON file.

```
string jsonString;
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myListOfInstances);
File.WriteAllText(FileName, jsonString);
```

When I'm opening the Application, I want the JSON file to be loaded to recreate the instances.
I'm using the following method, which apparently works well.

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
myListOfInstances = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(jsonString);
```

So far so good. When I check the content of the list, it is correctly populated and my 4 instances are there.
But then... how to use them?

Before the JSON, I was creating each instance (for example:)

```
MyClass FirstInstance = New MyClass();
FirstInstance.Type = EnumOfType.Type1;
FirstInstance.Price = 100.46;
```

Then I could manipulate it easily, simply calling FirstInstance.

```
myWindow.Label1.Content = FirstInstance.Price.ToString("C");
FirstInstance.Method1...
```

Now that the instances are in my list, I don't know how to manipulate them individually because I don't know how to call them.

It's probably obvious to most, but I'm still in the learning process.

Thank you for your help,

Fab

Comment: you could loop and use each instance, like `foreach(MyClass item in myListOfInstances){//manipulate item here}`

Comment: Are you asking how to access items in a list?

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Working "blindly" with items in a list, that's OK, I could do it.
When you create a variable (whatever the type), you're naming it. Th.anks to the name, you can manipulate one specific variable. That's what I'm trying to do.

Replace my 4 instances with a list on string. Each one is a specific text to be called in specific context. When the variable is named, it's easy.
Well, I suppose I just have to add a name property to my class and embed a "if" in the "foreach" loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how you have loaded the JSON file into your program, it looks like your variable myListOfInstances already contains all four MyClass objects ready to go. At this point you can use List accessors (or Linq if you want to be fancy) and do things such as the following:

```
myListOfInstances[0] //Gives you the first item in the list accessed by index
myListOfInstances.First() //Gives you the first item in the list (using linq)

foreach(var item in myListOfInstances) {
    // this will iterate through all four items in the list storing each instance in 
    //the 'item' variable
}
```

etc...

EDIT: From my comment below. If you need to access values in a a list directly, you can search for specific conditions in the list using linq with the 'Where' method. The syntax is something like this:

```
myListOfInstances.Where(x => x.Property == SomePropertyToMatch)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I guess is clearly shows that I'm far from understanding this object programming philosophy....

If I wanted to do the same thing to all my instances, that would be a perfest answer.
What I have in mind is that, I have a window with labels, textbox, etc.
I need values from each instance to be displayed in the correct box, in front of their label.
If I'm sure of the order of the instances in the JSON, it's all good. If not, how to place them where they belong without knowing their name.

Writing it, I feel it's not the good approach...

Comment: You could include some kind of identifier on each instance that you can reference without needing to loop through them? For example if you have an Id property in MyClass then you could access items like this:
myListOfInstances.Where(x => x.Id == someValue)

Comment: That's what I did and I can do whatever I want with my objects now.
Thank you very much!